# Git log relative date shortest form

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to make my git log shorter. I would like to have both the relative and the full date version:

```
* d01c261 2015-07-22 [-2d] A commit comment - John Doe (branch HEAD)
```

The `%ar` option gives something like `2 weeks ago` that might be rewritten `-2w`.

One ugly way to get this is:

```
git lg | perl -pe 's/(\d+) (\w)\w+ ago/-$1$2/'
```

What better solution (apart from using `tig` or `gitk`) can I use?